# Object to string delimited format

Tags: java, java-8

I have set of objects of different types.
**Ex** : Employee emp, adress adr

These two classes have list of properties

```
public class Employee{
private Stringname;
private int age;
}

public class Adress {
  private String HouseNo;
  private string Street;
  private string pin;
}
```

Each attribute is assigned with some 2 character value
`Name (NA), age (AG), HouseNo(HN),Street(ST), pin(PN)`

I need to construct a string with these data and delimit with a %

**Output:**

> NA%Vidhya%AG%30%HN%80%ST%1st cross%PN%100100

Comment: So what trouble are you facing?

Comment: Is that a question or a requirement?

Comment: How about using `StringJoiner`

Comment: I want to make it more generic using java8, here i have given only two classes, but there are multiple classes, also, how can i map the two character value to class attributes

Comment: you have two different object and you wanna add its properties in single toString() method ? or you want to create a string some other class using given objects ? what you exactly looking out ?

Comment: if you really need something like that, there 'll always be a way. first step would be to implement toString() in both classes

Comment: Don’t implement this with the toString() method that some suggests, it’s not how that method is meant to be used.

Comment: Is there any other way apart form toString(), I do not want to hard code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson unless the requirements need it to be, which seems to be the case

Comment: Need help in two things: 1)how can i map two char value to class properties 2)a logic to generate into string format with the data which are set into these attributes,

Comment: @Stultuske, read the documentation for toString() so you understand how/when it should be used. It’s not a “fix all” solution

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it is meant to provide a 'Returns a string representation of the object.', nowhere is it said this representation may not be formatted.

Comment: @Stultuske, it also says “concise but informative representation” which is important. Look, you can of course use toString here but it’s not a good practice. What if you want to write the object to a log file or inspect it in the debugger, then the toStringmethod is often used and then you probably do not want to see a string formatted for a specific requirement.

Comment: You are welcome to discuss your understanding of the documentation in the chat. For the question, explain what is your problem to implement this. Do you have difficulties to extract the "2" character part, ... to format the value, ... [edit] the question please. "_I need to construct_" is not enough, you need to show what you tried for us to point you in the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

Each class knows it own data best so I would let each class be responsible for generating the string. As I understand it the two char codes for each field are unique for each class and member and only used when generating the string so only the class would need them.

```
interface AttributeDescription {
    String generateDescription();
}

public class Employee implements AttributeDescription {
 //members...

   public String generateDescription() {
      return String.format(“NA%%%s%%AG%%%d”, name, age)
   }
```

Then simply call this method for all objects implementing the interface.

```
 AttributeDescription object = ...
 String attr = object.generateDescription();
```

I don't think it can be generalized more than this given the requirements.

*Update*

It might be better to have a builder class for building the string to get a more unified behavior between classes. Here is an example

```
public class AttributeBuilder {
  private builder = new StringBuilder();

  public String getAttribute() {
    return builder.toString();
  }

  public void add(String code, String value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return;
    }
    builder.append(code);
    builder.append(‘%’);
    builder.append(value);
    builder.append(‘%’);
  }
```

}

And then you would also have to implement add(...) methods for other data types in a similar fashion. The builder could then be used like

```
public String generateDescription() {
   AttributeBuilder builder = new AttributeBuilder();
   builder.add(“NA”, name);
   builder.add(“AG”, age);

   return builder.getAttribute();
}
```